# Problem with extracting dates from a database using php - all dates are the same

Tags: php, mysql

(Working on a guestbook type page.) All entries are displayed properly with their unique names/emails/comments, however the date marked on each entry outputted has the same exact date... the date of the latest entry. I've checked the database and the entries definitely have differing dates.

Code:

```
$get_query = "select Name, Email, Comment, Date from entries ORDER by Id DESC;";

                $get_rs = mysql_query($get_query);


                // While there are still results
                while($get_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_rs)) {

                    $name = stripslashes($get_row["Name"]);
                    $email = stripslashes($get_row["Email"]);
                    $comment = stripslashes($get_row["Comment"]);
                    $date2 = date('D, M j, Y', strtotime($get_row['date']));
                    $tableOpen ="<table align=\"center\"><th>$name</th><tr><td>";
                    $tableClose = "</td></tr></table>";
                    $gb_str2 .= $tableOpen;
                    if(!empty($name)) {
                        // If name exists and email exists, link name to email
                        if(!empty($email)) {
                            $name="by <a href=\"mailto:$email\">$name</a>";
                        }
                        else {

                            $name="";
                        }
                    // Else make name blank 
                    } else {
                        $name = "";
                    }

                    // Append to string we'll print later on
                    $gb_str2 .= "<br/>$comment<hr><font size=1>posted on $date2 $name".$tableClose."</font><br>";


                }
                echo $gb_str2;
```

For instance, every single post is recorded with "posted on Mon, Jul 11, 2011" today, although there were many posts entered on other dates.

Comment: What format is your date in in the database?  Just print it out as a string to make sure its in a valid format for strtotime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a case-sensitive issue.
In your select you have Date but in $get_row you have date. 
Change it to:

```
$date2 = date('D, M j, Y', strtotime($get_row['Date']));
```

Comment: Yup fixing the case sensitive should do the trick. was about to post the same answer! nice

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks!!